# Problema em atuzalizar as rotas do Láravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, route, artisan

Boa tarde. O problema é que quando edito o arquivo \routes\web.php ele não atualiza as rotas em execução. Este é o código:

``use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MidiumController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/teste', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

///Index do Dashboard
Route::get('/Dashboard_index', function(){
return view('Hbase/Dashboard/src/index');
});

//É a home, página principal da loja de roupas. Modificar para xamppAplimare_index_roupas.
//Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('about', 'AboutController');

Route::resource('footer', 'FooterController');

Route::resource('post','PostController');``

Criei para teste a rota /teste mas quando executo o comando php artisan route:list esta rota não está lá.

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando quando você faz o comando "php artisan route:list"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Isso está com cara de ser o cachê das rotas desatualizado,
utilize o comando no terminal:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Isso vai apagar o cache das rotas. Aconteceu alguns problemas parecidos comigo, principalmente quando ia para produção, aí o cachê estava desatualizado e as funções novas acabavam não funcionando. Mas fazendo a limpeza do cachê, isso se resolve.